# EFA on R: Classifying Observations

Tags: r, factor-analysis, psychometrics, exploratory-data-analysis

I am newbie for R and Stats. I am using EFA in R [psych library] to identify the latent factors underlying my data. I got a reasonable amount of factors matching my purpose.

My question is once I have the factors, is there a way to categorize observations based on the dominant factors, one or more?

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to try to classify people *before* doing the EFA, using e.g. cluster analysis which is designed for that purpose.

However, if, for some reason, you want to classify on the factors, I would first make a bunch of plots: Univariate density plots of each factor, then some bivariate plots, what else I would do depends on the number of factors. It might be obvious where the categorizations are, or it might be clear that there really aren't categories (this *often* happens; many things are continua). If neither is obvious, then you could try something like kernel densities.

Comment: Hi Peter, 

Thx for the reply. Actually I did try a k-means clustering beforehand and found out that there are some clusters. But I was looking for a more descriptive definition for cluster centers and thought EFA might help. So I applied EFA for the total data set.

Do you mean I should do the EFA for each cluster separately?

I am not familiar with the plots you mentioned I will do some reading on that. Thx.

Comment: No, I don't think EFA on each cluster would make sense. You might do cluster analysis on the factors....